# Trying to do a corellation coefficient but returning ridiculously high values

Tags: python, math, statistics

So before I begin here's the code:

```
from math import sqrt

def Summation(valueList):
    outValue = 0
    for item in valueList:
        outValue += item
    return outValue
def multSummation(vOne, vTwo):
    outValue = 0
    for item in range(0, len(vOne)):
        outValue += vOne[item] * vTwo[item]
    return outValue
def Correlator(xList=[],yList=[]):
    #r = n(Exy)-(Ex)(Ey) / sqrt([nEx^2-(Ex)^2][nEy^2-(Ey)^2])#God help me

    r = (len(xList) * multSummation(xList,yList)) - (Summation(xList) * Summation(yList)) / (sqrt((len(xList) * (multSummation(xList,xList)) - (multSummation(xList,xList) * multSummation(xList,xList))) * ((len(xList) * multSummation(yList,yList)) - (multSummation(yList,yList) * multSummation(yList,yList)))))
    return r

valOne = {1950:5,1955:9,1960:8,1965:3,1970:6,1975:7,1980:6}
valTwo = {1950:2,1956:5,1960:4,1965:1,1968:2,1975:3,1980:3}
matchingKeysList = []
for x in valOne.keys():
    for y in valTwo.keys():
        if x == y:
            matchingKeysList.append(x)
valOneCleaned = {}
valTwoCleaned = {}
for x in valOne:
    if x in matchingKeysList:
        valOneCleaned[x] = valOne[x]
for y in valTwo:
    if y in matchingKeysList:
        valTwoCleaned[y] = valTwo[y]

valOneList = []
valTwoList = []
for x in valOneCleaned:
    valOneList.append(valOneCleaned[x])
for y in valTwoCleaned:
    valTwoList.append(valTwoCleaned[y])


#MAIN LOOP HERE
print(valOneList)
print(valTwoList)
print(Correlator(valOneList, valTwoList))
```

This isn't a college project fyi. It basically takes two dictionaries, valOne and valTwo and cleans up the data so only the matching years between the two. Once this is done it takes the values and puts them into a list, then feeds it to the correlator function which takes in two lists and does a correlation coefficient between the two. The value should be between -1 and 1 but instead it ends up giving me ridiculously high numbers like 419.9. Please help my poor uneducated brain.

Comment: I've also tested the summation and multsummation functions and they seem to be returning proper values so I think the issue may be with the formula in the correlator function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parenthesis in the correlation formula is not correct. In your code, only a part of the numerator is actually divided by the denominator. Moreover, the formula for the denominator is not quite right. Try this:

```
r = ((len(xList) * multSummation(xList,yList)) - (Summation(xList) * Summation(yList))) / (sqrt((len(xList) * (multSummation(xList,xList)) - (Summation(xList) * Summation(xList))) * ((len(xList) * multSummation(yList,yList)) - (Summation(yList) * Summation(yList)))))
```

Rewritting the equation using multiple lines would be a lot easier to read and debug. And instead of using the `Summation` function, you can use the builtin `sum`

```
n = len(xList)
Ex = sum(xList)
Ey = sum(yList)
Exx = multSummation(xList,xList)
Exy = multSummation(xList,yList)
Eyy = multSummation(yList,yList)
numerator = n * Exy - Ex * Ey
denominator = sqrt(n * Exx - Ex * Ex) * sqrt(n * Eyy - Ey * Ey)
r = numerator / denominator
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks man. Also the tip for separating out the equation to different variables is a really good one man. I'll be sure to use that more often in the future. Thanks a bunch.